# Laravel 5.2 throws NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This happens when I add a basic route (foo). The rest of the routes work as expected. This generates a NotFoundHttpException and a ModelNotFoundException.

app/Http/routes.php:

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/index','WosController@index');
Route::get('/create','WosController@create');
Route::get('/{workorder}','WosController@show');
Route::post('/create','WosController@store');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return view('foo');
});
```

app/resources/views/foo.blade.php:

```
<p>foo</p>
```

Comment: Try to change the order of WosController@show declaration. Put it as the last route in the file.

Comment: That worked thanks! but why did it work?

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 it is on line 113 of Handler.php file ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When declaring your routes file, try to declare `WosController@show` as the last route. Like this:

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/index','WosController@index');
Route::get('/create','WosController@create');
Route::post('/create','WosController@store');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return view('foo');
});

Route::get('/{workorder}','WosController@show');
```

Laravel was probably making a mistake with your show route because it thinks that `/foo`is an argument of `{workorder}` since it has no way to differ them. So, when declaring routes, try to put fixed routes first and routes with arguments in the end.